# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb / firebase 10.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I run to this exception after a updated firebase messaging to 10.0.1.
before i had an older version but i need to update since i added some libraries "zopim" which uses an earlier version of google support so i

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.appsmedia.blaan2, PID: 15270
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.appsmedia.blaan2-1/base.apk)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5427)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5000)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4940)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1549)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

my project gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/exallium/maven" }
        maven { url "https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

my app gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.appcompat)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.support)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.support_annotations)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.design)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.dagger2)
apt(rootProject.ext.libs.dagger2_compiler)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.butterknife)
apt(rootProject.ext.libs.butterknife_compiler)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.rxandroid)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.rxjava)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.timber)
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.multidex)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.picasso)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.ormlite)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.recyclerview)
compile(rootProject.ext.libs.cardview)
compile group: 'com.zopim.android', name: 'sdk', version: '1.3.2.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
androidTestCompile(rootProject.ext.libs.mockito)
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:wakeful:1.1.+'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile 'org.joda:joda-money:0.9.1'
compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.7'
compile 'com.atomicleopard:expressive:0.9.5'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.2.Final'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.3.1@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.7.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar'
compile 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
compile 'com.race604.waveloading:library:1.1.0'
compile 'me.nlmartian.silkcal:library:0.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
compile 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.4'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
```

please i could not get this to work any suggestion, thanx in advance

Comment: Please debug app and check where it crashing..

Comment: @JadavLalit hi, yes i did and the application crashes and display the exception i mention above

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: @JadavLalit my probleme was the play-service version and the firebase version are not compatible thank you for your time.